# How to declare in Typescript a dictionary of Generic (in the TS sense) functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, generics

I want to create a series of functions of a *Generic* type called `Handler`. Each function gets different but quite specific parameters and returns specific responses, all stated in the *Generic* definition. A message containing a request with `RequestParams` comes in and a reply goes back.

A dictionary of such functions is passed to a `dispatcher` function that will, when called with the handler name and the arguments, to return whatever that function does. To make it simple I declared functions for CRUD operations (plus list) just because everyone knows those.

But my problem is that I have not been able to get rid of the last error, shown in the comment at the end. I tried several ways to do it and been playing whack-a-mole fixing one function and getting another popping up.

I believe I declared too much and made it too restrictive or didn't state the options right. What am I missing? Thanks for your patience.

```
type ID = string;
type VALUE = string | number | boolean | Date;
type AnyRow = Record<string, VALUE>;

// Default types for Id, In and Out
type DefaultId = ID | undefined;
type DefaultIn = AnyRow | undefined;
// Listings always return an array, even if an empty one, never undefined.
// Reads might return a row or undefined. Tried with `null` as well, to no avail.
type DefaultOut = AnyRow[] | (AnyRow | undefined);

// A handler might receive an Id or not, and it might accept (In) and return (Out) various responses
// - the return is actually a Promise.
// - There is actually a third input, a series of options,
//   such as, sort order, field to sort by, page to select
export type Handler<
  Id extends DefaultId,
  In extends DefaultIn,
  Out extends DefaultOut
> = (params: { id: Id; data: In }) => Out;

export type Handlers = Record<
  string,
  Handler<DefaultId, DefaultIn, DefaultOut>
>;

// Given a series of handlers, `createDispatcher` will return
// a function that when called with the key to a handler and
// an object with the id and data
// returns whatever that keyed function returns, if anything.
export const createDispatcher =
  (handlers: Handlers) =>
  (fnName: string, requestData: { id: DefaultId; data: DefaultIn }) =>
    handlers[fnName](requestData);

// These are the types for a typical CRUD series of handlers, plus list
// They represent the most common combinations of inputs and outputs.
type Resolvers<T extends AnyRow> = {
  list: Handler<undefined, undefined, T[] | undefined>;
  create: Handler<undefined, T, T>;
  read: Handler<ID, undefined, T | undefined>;
  update: Handler<ID, T, T>;
  delete: Handler<ID, undefined, undefined>;
};

type Data = { a: number };

const handlers: Resolvers<Data> = {
  list: () => [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }],
  read: ({ id }) => (id ? { a: 1 } : { a: 2 }),
  create: ({ data }) => data,
  update: ({ id, data }) => (id ? data : data),
  delete: ({ id }) => (id ? undefined : undefined),
};

// And here I create the actual dispatcher for the Data above
// with the text of the error shown below
export const dataDispatcher = createDispatcher(handlers);
//                                             ^^^^^^^^
// Argument of type 'Resolvers<Data>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Handlers'.
//   Property 'list' is incompatible with index signature.
//     Type 'Handler<undefined, undefined, Data[] | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Handler<DefaultId, DefaultIn, DefaultOut>'.
//       Type 'DefaultId' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
//         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3XdyW)

Comment: The comments are considerate but (at least in my opinion) this code is pretty easy to follow and the comments sort of make it harder (again, at least for me) to read.

Comment: I would change your `Handlers` type definition to `export type Handlers = Record<string, Handler<any, any, any>>;`. Solves the problem.

Comment: Tried with `any`, `undefined` and `unknown` just to get way more errors than I had before.

Comment: @kelly I tried again after copying the tsconfig on the Typescript Playground and it worked fine.   Thanks.   I had tried with `any` before but something in my setup didn't like it and still rejected it with my tsconfig.  I'll have to dig further into it.    The error is caused in a separate package in the same monorepo with different tsconfigs. I have to figure out how to figure that one for good.

Answer (score 0):

As @kelly pointed out in the comments, the solution is in changing this declaration:

```
export type Handlers = Record<
  string,
  Handler<DefaultId, DefaultIn, DefaultOut>
>;
```

to:

```
export type Handlers = Record<
  string,
  Handler<any, any, any>
>;
```

The issue was unrelated to the rest of the code shown above.

Sorry for the trouble and thanks.